# JAX-WS Deployement error + LocatableWebServiceException: class not found in runtime descriptor

Tags: deployment, tomcat, jax-ws

I have deployed JAX-WS web services in Tomcat and when i restarting the tomcat server. I am getting this error on console.

I have putted entry in web.xml and sun-jaxws.xml as per guidelines given in this link - 
http://www.jroller.com/eldaaran/entry/using_jax_ws_2_0

Please advise.

```
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: com.sun.xml.ws.util.exception.LocatableWebServiceException: class not found in runtime descriptor: webservices.jaxws.Math
at line 6 of jndi:/localhost/jaxws/WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml

com.sun.xml.ws.util.exception.LocatableWebServiceException: class not found in runtime descriptor: webservices.jaxws.Math at line 6 of jndi:/localhost/jaxws/WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.getImplementorClass(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:525)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:132)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:93)
```

Comment: Have you got any breakthrough for this issue ? I am facing same issue on tomcat 6

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the class webservices.jaxws.Math can't be found.

I can't find any reference to this class on the web, so I can only assume that it's a custom class, or the wrong namespace is being used.

Is there a `webservices/jaxws/Math.class` file?

Answer (score 0):

`webservices.jaxws.Math` seems to be your endpoint implementation class. Is this class well packaged and deployed? Are you sure it's in the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reference to Math in sun-jaxws.xml?  I think it is slightly more likely that java.lang.Math is being misnamed than that there is a webservices.jaxws.Math class (I don't see a copy in my version of jax-ws).